# Multi root with a GET request

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I am searching a way to map 2 different arrays with the following JSON

```
"establishments": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Boudin Sourdough Bakery and Cafe",
        "address": "1 Stockton St",
        "zip_code": "94108",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "country": "us",
        "phone_number": "",
        "position": {
            "latitude": 37.78590500000001,
            "longitude": -122.406289
        },
        "distance_from": 13.75783097391759
    }
],
"places": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Private Place",
        "position": {
            "latitude": 37.78583400000001,
            "longitude": -122.406417
        },
        "is_private": false,
        "distance_from": 0
    }
]
```

I have 2 different mappings. One for establishment and another for place. I found some help with the [documentation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#handling-multiple-root-objects-in-core-data-postput) but it's working only for PUT or POST requests.

Currently, I have the following request

```
[session.objectManager getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:APICallSearchSearchPlaceRouteName object:nil parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSArray * resultPlaces=mappingResult.array;

    [delegate APICallDidSearch:resultPlaces];
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSError* myError=[self catchCustomErrorInRKError:error setDomain:@"Search"];
    if (myError.code == NSURLErrorCancelled) return;

    [delegate APICallDidFailSearch:myError];
}];
```

Mapping & Mapping Descriptor

```
RKEntityMapping *establishmentMapping = [APICallEstablishment RKGetEstablishmentMappingForManagedObjectStore:self.appDelegate.managedObjectStore];
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:establishmentMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                   pathPattern:APICallSearchSearchPlacePattern
                                                                                       keyPath:@"establishments"
                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];


[session.objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

I tried to adapt the example to my case with that (just before my request written above)

```
RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [session.objectManager appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:establishmentMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET path:@"/whatever" parameters:nil];
operation.targetObject = nil;
//Does it still exist ? (XCode says an error)
//operation.targetObjectID = nil;
[session.objectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What are your mappings and descriptors? In what way is it working only for put and post?

Comment: I've just added this information to the main post. What I don't know is how to add multiple-root with the `operation`. With my current code, I can only give structure of one mapping (`establishmentMapping`).

Comment: I think I found something that could work but I can only extract one array (I've duplicated the operation for each mapping). Do you think it could be possible to extract 2 different arrays according to the type of elements mapped ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `session.objectManager getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed...` is a good option (better than trying to use `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` directly).

You need to create another response descriptor, like `responseDescriptor`, but for `places` key path and mapping.

Comment: It's exactly what I did. :-) 
I think I will manage by myself the split of the array. It seems much easier. Thank you for you help (again).